# Removing prefixes from link text using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a directory listing script that outputs the names of various organisations and their website address. The link that to the website that the user sees looks like http://www.whatever.com or http://whatever.com

To make things look a little prettier I'd like to remove the http:// element of the link. So the end result from the user perspective should, in html terms, look like 
    [justthedomainname.com](https://fulluneditedurl.com)

The way in which the php script is written and outputs makes doing this a little bit of a pain, and I thought it might be easier to accomplish with some javascript instead.

I initially tried something like:

```
<script>
var curInnerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
curInnerHTML = curInnerHTML.replace("http://", "");
document.body.innerHTML = curInnerHTML;
</script>
```

This however doesn't work, because it's looking for an exact string of "http://", when this will always be followed by the actual domain.

Any idea how I can accomplish this in pure JS?

Comment: Seems to me that it'd be easier to have the PHP produce the desired output in the first place.

Comment: Are there multiple links in `innerHTML`?

Answer (score 1):

You need a regex instead of a string. Something like this.

```
curInnerHTML = curInnerHTML.replace(/^https?:\/\//i, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to remove `http://www.` from a string containing URL of some website.

You can do it with regex

```
let result = url.replace(/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?/,'', '');
```

If you only want to strip `http://` and keep `www` then use this regex

```
let result = url.replace(/(^\w+:|^)\/\//,'', '');
```

Here is a working snippet

```js
let url =  "http://www.whatever.com";
let result = url.replace(/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?/,'', '');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for `<a>` elements exclusively *and* are only trying to replace the text content that the [user] sees:

```
document.querySelectorAll( 'a[href^="http"]' ).forEach( function ( current ) {
    current.textContent = current.href.split('//')[ 1 ];
} );
```

With a [caveat](https://davidwalsh.name/nodelist-array) about `.forEach()` on a `.querySelectorAll()` NodeList

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function remove(){
  
  var a = document.getElementById('target').getElementsByTagName('a');
  var attr;
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        attr = a[i].getAttribute("href").replace("http://", "");
        a[i].text = attr;
 
  }
  
}
 

remove();
```

```html
 <div id="target">
    <a href="http://test1.com">http://test1.com</a>
   <a href="http://test2.com">http://test2.com</a>
  </div>
```